# php : convert ressource stream in file

Tags: php, html, file

I get a ressource stream when I use fopen on a filepath I get from my database :

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT filepath
          FROM files
          WHERE id=123";
$result = do_query($query);
/*do_query() is a personal simplification*/
$line   = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$file   =   fopen($line['filepath'], 'r');
/*var_dump on file return "resource(51) of type (stream)"*/
?>
```

But I my project I need a $_FILE type... Can I convert a ressource stream in $_FILE type?

Comment: What is a "$_FILE" type...? Where do you need this?

Comment: $_FILE was file get in <input type='file'/>

Comment: In fact, I another part of my code, I use FILE. But now I need to make the same thing with file in my database. So I need to adapt "ressource of type stream" in "FILE"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_FILES` is not a "type", it's merely an array which holds certain information about uploaded files. First of all, if you have some piece of code which is hardcoded to use `$_FILES`, you should probably change it to accept a generic argument instead. Meaning, instead of:

```
function foo() {
    echo $_FILES['tmp_name']:
}
```

Rewrite that to:

```
function foo($path) {
    echo $path;
}
```

You can then call that function and pass it any path from anywhere. In your case you'd pass it `$line['filepath']` as is. You don't need to `fopen` it, because then you get a resource, when you currently just want a path.

If you need to "fake" the `$_FILES` array, you need to construct it manually:

```
$_FILES['foo']['name'] = '..';
$_FILES['foo']['type'] = '..';
$_FILES['foo']['size'] = '..';
$_FILES['foo']['tmp_name'] = $line['filepath'];
$_FILES['foo']['error'] = UPLOAD_ERR_OK;
```

But again, you'll probably want to alter whatever code is hardcoded to use `$_FILES` instead of this hackaround.